# On the finiteness and uniqueness of proofs in a Suppes system, among other things...

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I've run into the following question concerning the Suppes system of inference, that consists of the typical Modus Ponens, introduction and elimination rules and conditional and indirect proofs.

> Which of the following claims concerning the Suppes inference system are true?
>
> 1. If $\vdash_S\phi$, then the proof of the formula $\phi$ is finite.
> 2. If $\vdash_S\phi$, then the proof of the formula $\phi$ is unique.
> 3. There are a finite number of provable theorems in the Suppes system
> 4. If $\vdash_S\phi$, then $\Sigma\vdash_S\phi$ for any set of premises $\Sigma$.

Inference and provability are defined as follows:

> 1. A sentence $\phi$ can be *inferred* with the Suppes system *from a set of premises* $\Sigma$, denoted $\Sigma\vdash_S \phi$, if and only if there exists a Suppes-proof $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, so that $\alpha_n = \phi$ and the suppositional assumption or hypothesis $H_n = \emptyset$.
> 2. A sentence is a *theorem* or *provable* in a Suppes system, if and only if $\emptyset \vdash_S \phi$, or written more concisely, $\vdash_S\phi$.

#### My issue

I'm not sure what a finite proof is, or what it means for a proof to be unique. In the first place, I could pedantically add an infinite number of useless steps to a finite proof and make it infinite. This would only pose a problem to the first part of the definition (inferrability), but is the question asking about inferrability or provability? In the same vein, are two proofs the same, if they consist of the same steps in the same order, or does order not matter?

Second, How would I even begin to observe if there are a finite number of proofs in a system of inference?

Thirdly (and this is not really a question but more of a possibly wrong comment), I'm pretty sure that it doesn't make sense for us to be able to start from *any* set of premises $\Sigma$, and end up with a valid proof of an arbitrary theorem $\phi$. Isn't there a famous theorem that states something related to this? Something about incompleteness...?

Comment: Re 1), please re-read def 1. above: $α_1,\ldots, α_n$ , so that $α_n=\phi$

Comment: Re 2), you are right: the proof is **not** unique. Again, re-read the def of Suppes-proof.

Comment: 4) is related to 2) (and not to incompleteness).

Comment: Right, so a Suppes-proof is a *finite* sequence of applications of the Suppes inference rules to a non-empty set of premises, that ends in the sentence we want to prove. Therefore statement 1. is true, but the additon of useless steps makes it not unique. This also makes question 4. true, as the arbitrary useless steps can be added as premises. The number of provable theorems still eludes me, though.

Comment: Do you know the concept of *tautology* ? And that of *completeness* of the propositional calculus ?

Comment: Different approach: are you familiar with *sentence* (formula) of the language (e.g. $p \to p$) and schematic letters: $\phi$, etc used to "speak about" the calculus and its properties (metalogic) ?

Comment: I've heard all of those terms, but only *tautology* is truly familiar to me somewhat rigorously. It is a statement that is true regardless of the proposed premises.

Comment: $p \to p$ is taut; $(p \to p) \to (p \to p)$ is taut; $[(p \to p) \to (p \to p)] \to [(p \to p) \to (p \to p)]$ is taut; and so on. Completeness means that every tautology is a provable theorem of the system.

Comment: There is a section in our course material called "Flawlessness and completeness", under which the definition above is stated. There is also a theorem about sets of premises $\Sigma$ and sentences $\phi$, which states that $\Sigma\vdash_S\phi$, if and only if $\Sigma\vDash\phi$, and that $\vdash_S\phi$, if and only if $\vDash\phi$. But I don't know what the symbol $\vDash$ means, and it is not explained in the material, either.

Comment: Alternative: consider the "schematic" $\vdash \phi \to \phi$ (or: $\vdash \lnot \phi \lor \phi$) and its meaning.

Comment: Hmm, so what you're saying is that (discarding the limits of a finite alphabet), there are essentially an infinite number of tautologies, and the Suppes system is complete. Therefore there are an infinite number of provable claims in the system.